# Click on different area and hide divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set up a form with some upholders above the inputs. The thing is - how can I hide the upholders once the focus changes to another field?

The code snippet will help you understand my difficulty.

Thank you in advance,
João

```js
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inpt"));
var list = ["YOUR NAME", "YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS", "YOUR PHONE NUMBER"];
var upholder = document.getElementsByClassName("upholder");
var lol = document.getElementById("row-normal-3");

for (i = 0; i < upholder.length; i++) {
    upholder[i].classList.add("hide");
}

inputs.forEach(function slideUp(ipt, index) {
    ipt.addEventListener("click", function slideUpTwo() {
        upholder[index].classList.remove("hide");
        upholder[index].classList.add("show");
        upholder[index].innerHTML = list[index];
    })
})
```

```css
.show {
  display:flex;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="le-form">
                    <form method="POST">
                       <div class="le-input">
                           <div class="upholder"></div>
                           <input class="inpt" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
                       </div>
                       <div class="le-input">
                           <div class="upholder"></div>
                           <input class="inpt" type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your e-mail address">
                       </div>
                       <div class="le-input">
                           <div class="upholder"></div>
                           <input class="inpt" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
                       </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-btn">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide the upholders "  .. did you mean to hide text like "YOUR NAME" when you are on 2nd ? and hide "YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS" when you are on 3rd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide all of them first before applying the class changes to the specific one.

```js
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inpt"));
var list = ["YOUR NAME", "YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS", "YOUR PHONE NUMBER"];
var upholder = document.getElementsByClassName("upholder");
var lol = document.getElementById("row-normal-3");

for (i = 0; i < upholder.length; i++) {
  upholder[i].classList.add("hide");
}

inputs.forEach(function slideUp(ipt, index) {
  ipt.addEventListener("click", function slideUpTwo() {
    hideAllLabels();

    upholder[index].classList.remove("hide");
    upholder[index].classList.add("show");
    upholder[index].innerHTML = list[index];
  })
})

var hideAllLabels = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < upholder.length; i++) {
    upholder[i].classList.remove("show");
    upholder[i].classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: flex;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="le-form">
  <form method="POST">
    <div class="le-input">
      <div class="upholder"></div>
      <input class="inpt" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    </div>
    <div class="le-input">
      <div class="upholder"></div>
      <input class="inpt" type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your e-mail address">
    </div>
    <div class="le-input">
      <div class="upholder"></div>
      <input class="inpt" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide all the upholders before to show the particular focus element upholder.so Simply add the `forloop` inside the click function

```js
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inpt"));
var list = ["YOUR NAME", "YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS", "YOUR PHONE NUMBER"];
var upholder = document.getElementsByClassName("upholder");
var lol = document.getElementById("row-normal-3");

for (i = 0; i < upholder.length; i++) {
  upholder[i].classList.add("hide");
}

inputs.forEach(function slideUp(ipt, index) {
  ipt.addEventListener("click", function slideUpTwo() {

    for (i = 0; i < upholder.length; i++) { //hide all upholder
      upholder[i].classList.add("hide");
    }
    upholder[index].classList.remove("hide");
    upholder[index].classList.add("show");
    upholder[index].innerHTML = list[index];
  })
})
```

```css
.show {
  display: flex;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="le-form">
  <form method="POST">
    <div class="le-input">
      <div class="upholder"></div>
      <input class="inpt" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    </div>
    <div class="le-input">
      <div class="upholder"></div>
      <input class="inpt" type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your e-mail address">
    </div>
    <div class="le-input">
      <div class="upholder"></div>
      <input class="inpt" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mainly looking for

- an event that triggers if the element looses the focus
- an event that does not only trigger when the user clicks on the field but also when he presses `tab` to get into it.

I've rewritten your code to use `focus` instead of `click` to set the tooltip and `blur` to remove it. Works quite smooth.

Here's a list of the events HTML has in store for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

```js
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inpt"));
var list = ["YOUR NAME", "YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS", "YOUR PHONE NUMBER"];
var upholder = document.getElementsByClassName("upholder");
var lol = document.getElementById("row-normal-3");

for (i = 0; i < upholder.length; i++) {
    upholder[i].classList.add("hide");
}

inputs.forEach(function slideUp(ipt, index) {
    ipt.addEventListener("blur", function () {
        upholder[index].classList.add("hide");
        upholder[index].classList.remove("show");
    })

    ipt.addEventListener("focus", function slideUpTwo() {
        upholder[index].classList.remove("hide");
        upholder[index].classList.add("show");
        upholder[index].innerHTML = list[index];
    })
})
```

```css
.show {
  display:flex;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="le-form">
                    <form method="POST">
                       <div class="le-input">
                           <div class="upholder"></div>
                           <input class="inpt" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
                       </div>
                       <div class="le-input">
                           <div class="upholder"></div>
                           <input class="inpt" type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your e-mail address">
                       </div>
                       <div class="le-input">
                           <div class="upholder"></div>
                           <input class="inpt" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
                       </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-btn">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all the upholders before showing the current relative to the selected input. You can create a function like "hideAllUpHolders".
A separate function can be useful in case you need to hide all the upholders when the focus is given to an external element (only if required).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using **Array.Map()**.

For `upholder`, change made from:

```
var upholder = document.getElementsByClassName("upholder");
```

to (Convert HTML Node Collection to Array):

```
var upholder = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("upholder"));
```

For `click` event, change made from:

```
upholder[index].classList.remove("hide");
upholder[index].classList.add("show");
upholder[index].innerHTML = list[index];
```

to:

```
upholder.map(function (el, i) {index === i ? 
        (el.classList.add("show"), el.innerHTML=list[index]) : 
        (el.classList.remove("show"), el.innerHTML="")});
```

**Full solution:**

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".inpt"));
 var list = ["YOUR NAME", "YOUR E-MAIL ADDRESS", "YOUR PHONE NUMBER"];
 var lol = document.getElementById("row-normal-3");
 var upholder = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("upholder"));

 inputs.forEach(function slideUp(ipt, index) {
  ipt.addEventListener("click", function slideUpTwo() {
   upholder.map(function (el, i) {index === i ? 
                            (el.classList.add("show"), el.innerHTML = list[index]) :
       (el.classList.remove("show"), el.innerHTML = "")
   });
  })
 })
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
 .show {
  display: flex;
 }

 .hide {
  display: none;
 }
</style>

<div class="le-form">
 <form method="POST">
  <div class="le-input">
   <div class="upholder"></div>
   <input class="inpt" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
  </div>
  <div class="le-input">
   <div class="upholder"></div>
   <input class="inpt" type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Your e-mail address">
  </div>
  <div class="le-input">
   <div class="upholder"></div>
   <input class="inpt" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-btn">
 </form>
</div>
```